# Update customer gender translations

Tags: magento-1, customer, localisation, customer-attribute

I would like to translate the gender options for a customer. At first I thought that I could simply use a translation file for this, but looking into the template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/gender.phtml` I see that the option label is not passed to the translate function.

What is the best process for updating these values for different stores?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `gender` attribute is a dropdown attribute like any other one. Its labels are stored in the table `eav_attribute_option_value`.
But since there is no (out of the box) way to manage from the backend the customer attributes I see 2 options here.

**Option 1.**  Quick and dirty:
Change the options in the template.
Copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/gender.phtml` to your theme and add after

```
 <?php $options = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions();?>
```

this:

```
<?php foreach ($options as $key => $option) : ?>
    <?php $options[$key]['label'] = $this->__($option['label']);?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Then you can translated the values like any other string.

**Option 2** - Long but clean.
Insert into the table `eav_attribute_option_value` the values for your second (and third and so on..) store view.

I said that this is the 'clean' version.
The theory it's clean but the solution I have it's not that clean.

Identify the attribute id:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'gender';
```

Let's say it's 1000.
then identify the options for the attribute

```
select * from eav_attribute_option where attribute_id = 1000;
```

Let's say you get 100 and 101.
Then look in the `eav_attribute_option_value` to see which is which.

```
select * from eav_attribute_option_value where option_id in (100, 101);
```

now you will see which is the `Male` option and which is the `Female` option.

Let's say `100 => Male`, `101=>Female`.
Now insert your values for the second store store.

```
Insert into `eav_attribute_option_value` set option_id = 100, store_id = 1, value = 'Translation for Male here'; 
Insert into `eav_attribute_option_value` set option_id = 101, store_id = 1, value = 'Translation for Female here';
```

Sorry but I don't have an upgrade script version for this.

I would go with the quick and dirty one. Fewer headaches.

Comment: Perfect, well apart from not having an update script version ;)

Comment: @DavidManners. Then it's not perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, is to update (override) `widget/gender.phtml` to enable translation.

from :

```
<?php foreach ($options as $option):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' selected="selected"' ?>><?php echo $option['label'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

to :

```
<?php foreach ($options as $option):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' selected="selected"' ?>><?php echo $this->__($option['label']) ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And finally, add your translate text in `Mage_Customer.csv`, like this :

```
"Male","Your translate for Male"
"Female","Your translate for Female"
```

Don't forget to clear the cache in `system > cache management`

---

**EDIT 07 sept. 2015**

I asked for a pull request on Magento2, see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/1801

Answer (score 0):

Working update script ... just need to adjust `$labels` variable to match your store IDs ...

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$labels = array(
    'Male' => array(    # default value
        1 => 'Male-DE', # key is storeId
        2 => 'Male-FR'
    ),
    'Female' => array(
        1 => 'Female-DE',
        2 => 'Female-FR'
    )
);

$attributeCode = 'gender';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getResource()
    ->getAttribute($attributeCode);

$values = array();
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    foreach ($labels as $label => $translations) {
        if ($optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($label)) {
            $values[$optionId] = array(0 => $label) + $translations;
        }
    }
}

$data = array();
$data['option']['value'] = $values;

$attribute->addData($data);
try {
    $attribute->save();
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easily way

Find out the attributes

select * from eav_attribute_option_value where option_id in (select option_id from eav_attribute_option where attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'gender'))

Now just do our update

:D

Comment: Initial question was asking about using translations, this will not work for that.