# how to translate gender options?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

this question was already asked for magento 1 --> [Update customer gender translations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/update-customer-gender-translations/82013#82013)

could anyone help me to translate male/female in magento 2?